# Using Ant To Build War As a Folder

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant, war

I am using ant to build my war to deploy it. But ant builds the war as a file "webapp.war". I need to build it as a folder "webapp.war" how can I do it using ant?

```
   <target name="war" depends="compile"> 
      <war destfile="dist/AntExample.war" 
webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml" keepcompression="false"> 
         <fileset dir="WebContent"/> 
         <lib dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib"/> 
         <classes dir="build/classes"/>
        </war> 
    </target>
```

Comment: <target name="war" depends="compile">
  <war destfile="dist/AntExample.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml" keepcompression="false">
   <fileset dir="WebContent"/>
   <lib dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib"/>
   <classes dir="build/classes"/>
  </war>
 </target>

Comment: It's correct behavior of <war>. Do you mean you want to copy the staff to folder "webapp.war" instead of standard file "webapp.war"?

Comment: thnaks for Attention so much.I found another solution.I use unzip task to extract "webapp.war" in existing folder

Answer (score 4):

try this...works for me

```
<target name="war" depends="compile">
    <war destfile="dist/deployme_temp.war" webxml="web/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="web"/>
        <lib dir="web/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        <classes dir="build/classes"/>
    </war>
</target>

<target name="unzip" depends="war">
    <unzip src="dist/deployme_temp.war" dest="dist/deployme.war" />
</target>


<target name="copy-war" depends="unzip">
       <copy todir="${deploy.destination}/deployme.war" overwrite="true">
         <fileset dir="dist/deployme.war"/>
       </copy>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

try [copy task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) (assume you are using Eclipse Dynamic Web Project layout):

```
<property name="dist"  location="webapp.war"/>
<target name="war folder"  depends="compile"  description="generate the distribution" >
   <mkdir dir="${dist}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
   <copy todir="${dist}">
      <fileset dir="WebContent"/>
   </copy>

   <copy todir="${dist}/WEB-INF/classes">
     <fileset dir="yourClassDir"/>
   </copy>
   <!-- other stuff to copy-->
</target>
```